# How to add Tags to ECS existing Service, Task definition using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I have a requirement to add tags to all ECS services, task definition and tasks.
I just added below to add tags to my existing code. when new service is creating tags getting added and propagating which is good, But when I tried to add tags to existing ecs service its creating same service by destroying the existing one.
How to add tags  without recreating existing ECS service, and should propagate tags to tasks when task rotated

```
    tags = {
    Name = local.name_env
    name2 = local.name2
    owner = var.sowner
    env = var.env
  }
  propagate_tags = "SERVICE"
```

Comment: I believe you'd either have to use data sources https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ecs_service to reference the existing resource or import the existing resources https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import

Comment: for existing ecs service tags updated manually, but its not propagating to tasks has propagate_tags = "SERVICE" was not checked while creating service initially. after creating service we dont have option to update to select propagate_tags = "SERVICE".  am looking for options to propagate tags from service without destroying existing and create new service

Answer (score 0):

i think you can used terraform state command for this . just add the tag manually in ecs then add the same thing in terraform tfstate file it should work i guess .

Comment: I added  "propagate_tags": "SERVICE", in tfstate file and updated tags on services. restarted the tasks but new task do not have tags